# How to pass options to dnf when using Ansible

Tags: ansible, centos, dnf

When installing packages through the Ansible's `dnf` module. How do I pass options like `--nobest` to `dnf`? Is there alternative to using raw shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem (but i'm using yum package manager) and figured a work around [here](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-docker/issues/171#issuecomment-557450810)

```
The issue is that docker-ce has not been packaged for CentOS 8 yet.

An ugly workaround is to install containerd.io manually beforehand:

pre_tasks:
  - yum:
     name: https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

So, try to set full package url as package name and it should definitely work.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`nobest` can be passed as a parameter while using the DNF module in the playbook

You can refer here [dnf_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dnf_module.html) for other options/parameters that can be passed to the dnf ansible module

For example :

```
- name: Install the latest version of Apache from the testing repo
  dnf:
    name: httpd
    enablerepo: testing
    state: present

- name: Install the latest version of Apache
  dnf:
    name: httpd
    state: present
    nobest: false
```

Comment: that works only if you are not on Redhat / Cent OS / Oracle Linux,they do not have the nobest option https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/dnf_module.html